# Dynamic query params for React Native Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a phonebook app in which I'm implementing a search bar.

I am trying to use the useNavigate hook to take a string {term} and navigate to the search page along with the term the user typed in.
So for example if the user typed in David the address bar would be
http://localhost:3002/search?q=David

At the moment when I type David into search bar I get this result in address bar
http://localhost:3002/search
The parameter was not passed along to the search page.

I followed the instruction here which said I should do following
navigate('search', {term}) but this did not work for me

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Any help appreciated

Searchbar.js

```
import "./Searchbar.css"
import { useState } from "react"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"



export default function Searchbar() {
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    const handleSubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        navigate('search', {term})
        console.log(term)
    
    }

    return (
        <div className="searchbar">
           <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <label htmlFor="search">Search Contacts</label>
           <input
           type="text"
           onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)}
           value={term}>
           </input>
           </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Navbar.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./Navbar.css"
import Searchbar from "./Searchbar";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <nav>
        <Link to="/" className="brand"><h1>Phonebook</h1></Link>
        <Searchbar></Searchbar>
        <Link to="/create">Create Contact</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should work.

```
navigate({
  pathname: "search",
  search: {
    q: term,
  },
});
```

For more you can have a look [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7743)

Comment: Thanks for the help, followed your link and got code working as follows ```navigate({
            pathname: "search",
            search: '?' + createSearchParams({ q: term})
          })} ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).